Увеличение размера диска linux
Дано:
Есть сервер на linux без админских прав.
В домашней папке(/home/User1) для доступного пользователя всего 4 гб(и уже забито).
Есть папка с доступом (/u01) на 5 тб.
Проблема: при удаленной установке(например, IDE Jetbrains) пытается поставить сначала все в home, а места нет.
Вопрос: можно ли как-то увеличить объем /home/User1? Пробовал делать ссылки через ln, не помогло(или не так сделал)

Заранее узнать, в какую папку оно будет устанавливаться, и сделать ее симлинком в /u01/.... Или это не сработало?

Не сработало, все равно пытается ставить в home

А что он делает? Удаляет симлинк и заменяет на обычную папку?

Пытается поставить в home, видит, что нет места и возвращает ошибку, файлы не записываются

если не ln -s /u01/IDEs /home/User1/ то можно попробовать перед установкой export HOME=/u01/User1.
